# random shutdown? (logfiles included)

Tags: kernel-panic

My iMac (OS X El Capitan 10.11.1 newly installed on 27.11.2015) keeps shutting down randomly and restarting for about one and a half month now. Sometimes it even shuts down during the restart caused by the last random shutdown.

After the restart there is no popup saying it restarted after a problem or something like this. Sometimes it shuts down after a few minutes, sometimes it runs smoothly for some hours.

I had the hardware checked at a local store, but there was no hardware issue found. 
They did a system analysis and allegedly couldn't reproduce the error, and only installed El Capitan (before I had Maverick, the shutdowns occured there also).

For the last shutdown I was able to save the logs:

---

```
Time                   Bundle ID                  Status    Comment
0.000                          -                       -    TALagent        
Started (system uptime: 40.71 sec, current time: 470496758.81)
0.004                          -                       -    Liveness: 0     
-> 1 (run_as_server)
0.005                          -                       -    Liveness: 1 
-> 2 (create_xpc_listener)
0.005                          -                       -    Blocking app 
contact
 0.013                         -                       -    Successfully read encryption key from keychain in 0.00904495 seconds
0.122                          -                       -    Liveness: 2     
-> 3 (server_show_windows_for_asns)
 0.123                         -                       -    server_show_windows_for_asns start
0.123                          -                       -    Allowing apps to contact us
0.124                          -                       -    TAL launch still in progress because com.apple.Photos is unstopped (no) and/or unhidden (yes)
0.124                          -                       -    Still waiting for registration from com.apple.Photos, com.apple.Safari, com.apple.mail, Finder
0.124                          -                       -    Liveness: 3 -> 4 (add_app)
0.125           com.apple.Photos               Launching    
0.175           com.apple.Photos                       -    Failed to create a window image: Failed to read metadata for file '/Users/matthiasweber/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Photos.savedState/window_2.data'. errno is 2 (No such file or directory)
0.179           com.apple.Safari               Launching    
 0.207          com.apple.Safari                       -    Failed to create a window image: Failed to create an image from file path 
 /Users/matthiasweber/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Safari.savedState/window_1.data
 0.208            com.apple.mail               Launching    
 0.234                         -                       -    Finder not yet launched, but pretending it is
 0.266          com.apple.finder                       -    Failed to create a window image: Failed to create an image from file path /Users/matthiasweber/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.finder.savedState/window_3.data
 0.266          com.apple.finder                       -    Failed to create a window image: Failed to create an image from file path /Users/matthiasweber/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.finder.savedState/window_2.data
 0.266                         -                       -    loginwindow launched apps com.apple.Photos, com.apple.Safari, com.apple.mail
 0.266                         -                       -    Bitmaps Ready (3 apps, 0 windows)
0.272           com.apple.Photos                       -    Disposing because it has no windows
 0.273          com.apple.Photos                Disposed    
 0.273          com.apple.Safari                       -    Disposing because it has no windows
 0.274          com.apple.Safari                Disposed    
 0.274            com.apple.mail                       -    Disposing because it has no windows
 0.274            com.apple.mail                Disposed    
 0.274          com.apple.finder                       -    Disposing because it has no windows
 0.274          com.apple.finder                Disposed    
 0.274                         -                       -    server_show_windows_for_asns end
 0.277                         -                       -    TAL launch still in progress because com.apple.Photos is unstopped (yes) and/or unhidden (yes)
 0.277                         -                       -    Still waiting for registration from com.apple.Photos, com.apple.Safari, com.apple.mail, Finder
 0.277                         -                       -    TAL launch still in progress because com.apple.Photos is unstopped (yes) and/or unhidden (yes)
0.277                          -                       -    Still waiting for registration from com.apple.Photos, com.apple.Safari, com.apple.mail, Finder
 0.523                         -                       -    TAL launch still in progress because com.apple.Photos is unstopped (yes) and/or unhidden (yes)
0.523                          -                       -    Still waiting for registration from com.apple.Photos, com.apple.Safari, com.apple.mail, Finder
 1.119                         -                       -    TAL launch still in progress because com.apple.Photos is unstopped (yes) and/or unhidden (yes)
 1.119                         -                       -    Still waiting for registration from com.apple.Photos, com.apple.Safari, com.apple.mail, Finder
 2.274                         -                       -    Liveness: 4 -> 3 (__remove_app_block_invoke)
 2.569                         -                       -    TAL launch still in progress because com.apple.Photos is unstopped (yes) and/or unhidden (yes)
 2.569                         -                       -    Still waiting for registration from com.apple.Photos, com.apple.Safari, com.apple.mail, Finder
 3.303                         -                       -    Liveness: 3 -> 2 (__create_xpc_listener_block_invoke)
 3.645          com.apple.finder                       -    Finder checked in
 3.645                         -                       -    TAL launch still in progress because com.apple.Photos is unstopped (yes) and/or unhidden (yes)
3.645                          -                       -    Still waiting for registration from com.apple.Photos, com.apple.Safari, com.apple.mail
3.904                          -                       -    TAL launch still in progress because com.apple.Photos is unstopped (yes) and/or unhidden (yes)
3.904                          -                       -    Still waiting for registration from com.apple.Photos, com.apple.Safari, com.apple.mail
 4.306                         -                       -    TAL launch still in progress because com.apple.Photos is unstopped (yes) and/or unhidden (yes)
 4.306                         -                       -    Still waiting for registration from com.apple.Photos, com.apple.Safari, com.apple.mail
 5.089          com.apple.Safari                       -    Registered as TAL ready
 5.089                         -                       -    TAL launch still in progress because com.apple.Photos is unstopped (yes) and/or unhidden (yes)
 5.089                         -                       -    Still waiting for registration from com.apple.Photos, com.apple.mail
 10.128                        -                       -    Assuming that all apps that will be started, have been started. Stopped apps will no longer delay TAL launch completion.
 10.128                        -                       -    TAL launch still in progress because com.apple.Photos is unstopped (yes) and/or unhidden (yes)
10.128                         -                       -    Still waiting for registration from com.apple.Photos, com.apple.mail
11.550            com.apple.mail                       -    Registered as TAL ready
11.550                         -                       -    TAL launch still in progress because com.apple.Photos is unstopped (yes) and/or unhidden (yes)
 11.550                        -                       -    Still waiting for registration from com.apple.Photos
 15.003                        -                       -    Liveness: 2 -> 1 (__run_as_server_block_invoke)
 15.816         com.apple.Photos                       -    Registered as TAL ready
 15.816                        -                       -    All started apps have registered (no remaining unregistered apps)
 15.817                        -                       -    TAL Relaunch - all apps registered as ready
 15.817                        -                       -    Liveness: 1 -> 0 (__server_show_windows_for_asns_block_invoke30)
 15.817                        -                       -    Exiting out of boredom
```

---

Can anyone see from this log what is causing the shutdown?

Please feel free to ask more questions if you need additional information.
I appreciate any tips or help!

Comment: When you restart or shutdown your Mac normally, is the "Reopen windows when logging back in" checkbox checked in the pop-up window? Likewise, in `System Preferences > General` is the "Close windows when quitting an app" checkbox unchecked? I suggest unchecking the pop-up window at restart/shutdown time, and checking the "Close windows..."  in `System Preferences` and see if the problem goes away. (BTW/ I did get a chuckle out of the error message: `Exiting out of boredom`.)

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I just tried it and no shutdown happend yet. So I will continue and observe the behaviour.